# Uploading files to Discord API thought PUT using python requests

Tags: python, api, python-requests, discord, put

I have a problem while trying to upload files to discord.
If I get it right, algorithm of uploading files to discord is next:
I am sending information about the file that i want to upload, discord sending me link where i must put the file, i am put the file to the address given.

I have this code:

```
def Upload(link, channel, token):
  api_url = 'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/'+channel+'/attachments'
  file_name = link[-10:]
  file_id = 1
  response = requests.get(link)
  open(file_name, "wb").write(response.content)
  file_size = os.path.getsize(file_name)
  upload = {"files":[{"filename":file_name,"file_size":file_size,"id":file_id}]}
  file = open(file_name, 'rb')
  header = {'authorization' : token}
  response = requests.post(api_url, headers=header, json=upload)
  put_url = response.json()['attachments'][0]['upload_url']
  put_name = response.json()['attachments'][0]['upload_filename']
  put_headers = {'Content-Length': str(file_size), 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Type': 'image/png', 'authorization' : token}
  response = requests.put(put_url, headers=put_headers, data=file)
  return response
```

As first sight everything seems to be working. Response code is 200, everything ok.
But if I try to get headers - print(response.headers), I've got next message:

> {'X-GUploader-UploadID': 'bla-bla-bla', 'ETag': '"bla-bla"', 'x-goog-generation': '1682338706931190', 'x-goog-metageneration': '1', 'x-goog-hash': 'bla-bla-bla', 'x-goog-stored-content-length': '1112324', 'x-goog-stored-content-encoding': 'identity', 'Vary': 'Origin', 'Content-Length': '0', 'Date': 'Mon, 24 Apr 2023 12:18:26 GMT', 'Server': 'UploadServer', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'}

I've got: 'Content-Length' = '0', 'Content-Type' = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'. And changing the "put_headers" does not affect it, absolutely.  I've sent 1112324 bytes, wtf? I see the 'x-goog-stored-content-length' = '1112324', but I dont know what's going wrong.
In addition, if I'm trying to use the "uploaded" attachment in next message - I'm recieving error (wrong attachment).
What I'm doing wrong?

I tried to use POST, but discord does not accept this method for attachments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the row 'file_id = 1'
I tried to change it to 'file_id = 0' and all started to work!
@AKX thank you for help and for very good advice about tempfile and raise_for_status. Its very useful!

Answer (score 1):

The response is as expected – the *response's* content length is zero (since there's nothing to say – "200 OK" to tell you it was fine and the metadata in the header is enough).

I think you'll find the actual read URL for the attachment in that `response.json()['attachments']` list.

To clean your code up a bit (e.g. using a temporary file so it gets automagically cleaned up, and calling `raise_for_status()` so you get exceptions when they arise), you might want

```
import tempfile

import requests


def Upload(link, channel, token):
    file_name = link[-10:]
    data_response = requests.get(link)
    data_response.raise_for_status()
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile("w+b") as file:
        # Write the data to a temporary file
        file.write(data_response.content)
        file.flush()
        file_size = file.tell()
        # Seek back to the start
        file.seek(0)
        api_response = requests.post(
            f"https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channel}/attachments",
            headers={"authorization": token},
            json={"files": [{"filename": file_name, "file_size": file_size, "id": 1}]},
        )
        api_response.raise_for_status()
        attachment_info = api_response.json()["attachments"][0]
        put_url = attachment_info["upload_url"]
        put_response = requests.put(
            put_url,
            headers={
                "Content-Length": str(file_size),
                "Content-Type": "image/png",
                "authorization": token,
            },
            data=file,
        )
        put_response.raise_for_status()
    return attachment_info
```

(You also could just use an `io.BytesIO()` to not touch the disk at all, since you're not `stream`ing the original response in the first place.)

Comment: Seems like, there is no json response, because if i trying to get print(response.json()), he writes the next error:
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: You're overwriting `response` three times in your original code, mind.

Comment: If Im trying to use attachment in the next message (usually its using attachment parameters that i described on first step) - "attachments":[{"id":file_id,"filename":file_name,"uploaded_filename":put_name}] - it throws error "wrong attachment"

Comment: INTERACTION_APPLICATION_COMMAND_OPTIONS_INVALID_ATTACHMENT - discord answer when Im trying to use attachment